# Magento 2: Can't run magento setup:upgrade on mamp

Tags: magento2, module, database

Newbie here:

I have downloaded the latest copy of Magento 2.2.5

I have manually added the Molly theme

I get to this part of the installation where I need to enable some modules but I can't run setup:upgrade: [Molly 2 Documentation](http://magesolution.com/themes/molly/docs2/index.html#toc13)

**This is the screenshot from enabling a module**

[image: Enabling module]

**This is the screenshot from trying to run setup:upgrade**

[image: Error I get when trying to run setup:upgrade]

Also after enabling the modules, I can't get to the website and looking at /var/report/ it says I have to run the setup:upgrade but am unable to. Please help!

**system.log shows:**

> [2018-08-24 18:33:10] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the
>   temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please
>   update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which
>   decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size:
>   100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool
>   size: 134217728 bytes. [] [] [2018-08-24 18:33:10] main.WARNING:
>   Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of
>   innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or
>   decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the
>   temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size:
>   50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
>   [2018-08-24 18:33:10] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the
>   temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please
>   update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which
>   decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size:
>   100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool
>   size: 134217728 bytes. [] [] [2018-08-24 18:33:10] main.WARNING:
>   Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of
>   innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or
>   decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the
>   temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size:
>   50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
>   [2018-08-24 18:33:11] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the
>   temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please
>   update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which
>   decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size:
>   100000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool
>   size: 134217728 bytes. [] [] [2018-08-24 18:33:11] main.WARNING:
>   Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of
>   innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or
>   decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the
>   temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size:
>   50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []

**Running php -v**
PHP 7.1.7 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2017 18:08:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

Comment: Please check logs and post full stack trace.

Comment: @VivekKumar I should probably mention that I'm new to all this and terminal so I don't quite understand.

Comment: Please clear/rename   files /var/logs/exception.log and  /var/logs/system.log , run the command and then paste the contents of these files (regenerated) here.

Comment: There wasn't an exception.log. I renamed system.log and when I ran the command, there was no new system.log file that got generated. But this is what I got below:

Comment: Kindly edit the question and paste these info there, so it is visible to rest of the user too

Comment: Also, think it is due php not properly configured .. run php -v command and see if the error appears there as well

Comment: @VivekKumar Okies, information is added

Comment: open app/bootstrap.php and in the begining of the file paste code :  ini_set('memory_limit', -1);

Comment: Also follow - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_phpini.html

Comment: @VivekKumar so I created a phpinfo.php and found the php.ini location. When I do the command line php -i | grep 'php.ini', it just displays "Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc" which I don't understand what I'm suppose to do with that.